# Docusign API - request for signature using Template

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to test the REST API for request a signature on a document referenced through a template using C# in a WCF webservice.

The Step 1 for Login works & returns the accountID & baseURl;

The Step 2 fails with a `Bad Request`.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    ...
    string requestBody = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
            "<accountId>" + accountId + "</accountId>" +
            "<status>" + "sent" + "</status>" +
            "<emailSubject>" + "API Call for Embedded Sending" + "</emailSubject>" +
            "<emailBlurb>" + "This comes from C#" + "</emailBlurb>" +
            "<templateId>" + "9A535489-0FB6-42B2-82C1-A06DA36025B4" + "</templateId>" +
            "<templateRoles>" +                       
            "<email>" + "abc@gmail.com" + "</email>" +  // NOTE: Use different email address if username provided in non-email format!
            "<name>" + "GRAVITY1003" + "</name>" +              // username can be in email format or an actual ID string
            "<roleName>" + "GRAVITY1003" + "</roleName>" +
            "</templateRoles>" +
            "</envelopeDefinition>";

    // append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and use in the request
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseURL + "/envelopes");
    request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Accept = "application/xml";
    request.ContentLength = requestBody.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    // write the body of the request
    byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(body, 0, requestBody.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    // read the response
    webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();------> It fails here
    sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    uri = responseText;
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
    {
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
        Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
        using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ? I looked at the API walkthrough's & coded this accordingly. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a bug in the Gist you were working off of, the wrong version was mistakenly uploaded.  The Gist has been fixed, the issue was just one xml node that was missing.

Since you can have multiple template roles on a given template, there needs to be an extra xml node that separates each role.  What you need to do is add singular `<templateRole></templateRole>` xml nodes in between the `<templateRoles></templateRoles>` nodes.

So your request body should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <accountId>123456</accountId>
   <status>sent</status>
   <emailSubject>API Call for sending signature request from template</emailSubject>
   <emailBlurb>This comes from Java</emailBlurb>
   <templateId>EA64D446-3BFA-*********************</templateId>
   <templateRoles>
      <templateRole>
         <email>recipient_email_address</email>
         <name>recipient_name</name>
         <roleName>template_role_name</roleName>
      </templateRole>
   </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```